# Edit RC file from add-in

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I am trying to edit a win32 RC file from my add-in and add some strings in the string table. It seems the there is no extensibility support in VcProjectEngine for this. I have managed to edit it as re regular text file but VS prompts me to reload every time. Has someone discovered another solution?

Thanks